# Room Query - "SELECT * FROM limit_orders where is_active=0 ORDER BY fill_date DESC" - not ordering list

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have this Room Query as so:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM limit_orders where is_active=0 ORDER BY fill_date DESC")
LiveData<List<Order>> getFilledOrders();
```

and I'm expecting to get a descending list, but it's not ordering the list.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Order code and the example values of the fill_date column.